# Find $Cov(X,Y) $ for $f(x,y)=e^{-y}$, where $0 \leq x \leq y$ and $E[Y|X]=x+1$:

Tags: probability, statistics, expectation, conditional-expectation, covariance

Find $Cov(X,Y) $ for $f(x,y)=e^{-y}$, where $0 \leq x \leq y$ (and $E[Y|X]=x+1$ that I found in a later part of the problem):

I know that $Cov(X,Y)=E[XY]-E[X]E[Y]$, where I think $E[XY]=E[xE[Y|X]]=E[x(x+1)]=E[x^2+x]=\int_{x}^\infty \int_{0}^y (x^2+x)(e^{-y})dxdy$

However the integration gets very difficult and I am not sure on the bounds of integration. Is there a simpler way to find the $cov(X,Y)$?

Comment: The joint density function is bereft of x, Is there a problem?

Comment: @satishramanathan Actually, the joint PDF $f(x,y)=e^{-y}\mathbf 1_{0<x<y}$ does involve $x$, thus, no problem there. On the other hand, $E(Y\mid X)=x+1$ is wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a confusion here. Let's start from the product. I will use indices to explicitly denote with respect to which PDF we are computing the expected value:
\begin{eqnarray*}
E_{X,Y}[XY]&=&\int\limits_0^{\infty}\int\limits_x^{\infty}xyf_{X,Y}(x,y)dydx\\
&=&\int\limits_0^{\infty}\int\limits_x^{\infty}xyf_{Y|X}(y|x)f_X(x)dydx\\
&=&\int\limits_0^{\infty}xf_X(x)\int\limits_x^{\infty}yf_{Y|X}(y|x)dydx\\
&=&\int\limits_0^{\infty}xf_X(x)E_{Y|X}[Y|X]dx\\
&=&\int\limits_0^{\infty}(x^2+x)e^{-x}dx\\
\end{eqnarray*}
The last step is because $E_{Y|X}[Y|X]$ is only a function of $X$, not $Y$. Now, my calculations show that:
$$E[XY]=3$$
and after finding the marginal PDFs of $X$ and $Y$ that $E[X]=1$ and $E[Y]=2$.

Comment: Thank you, but how do you get 1 for E[X]? I am using $E[X]=\int_{0}^y xe^{-x}dx$ and getting something else.

Comment: @SilviaRossi First, the PDF of $X$ is $f_X(x)=e^{-x}$ and its support cannot depend on $y$ so it's from $0$ to $\infty$ so $E[X]=\int_0^{\infty}xe^{-x}dx$. Or, you can see it as exponential for $\lambda=1$ (see d.k.o.'s answer) with known mean $1/\lambda$.

Comment: I'm sorry for all the questions. Could you explain to me why d.k.o's method is incorrect? I don't see why you and him got different answers because both methods seem correct to me.

Comment: @SilviaRossi My mistake. So the idea for the bounds is that you let $x$ free from $0$ to $\infty$ at the outer integral and you constrain $y$ based on $x$ at the inner integral. This is because the result must be independent of $x,y$. I think (please check) that the same result can be achieved by $E[XY]=\int\limits_0^{\infty}\int\limits_0^yxyf_{X,Y}(x,y)dxdy$. I have edited the answer.

Comment: "I will use indices to explicitly denote with respect to which PDF we are computing the expected value" Sorry but this is **never** useful.

Comment: @Did I find it useful sometimes. Makes things clear.

Comment: @mgus Hmmm... Actually one could document the confusion this unnecessary notation creates, simply by perusing the questions on this site... But say, according to you, what would be the meaning of $$E_X(\sin(XY))\ ?$$

Answer (score 1):

The marginal distribution of $X$ is $f_X(x)=\int_{x}^\infty e^{-y}dy=e^{-x}$ (exponential with mean and variance equal $1$). Then $\mathsf{E}X^2+\mathsf{E}X=\operatorname{Var}(X)+(\mathsf{E}X)^2+\mathsf{E}X=3$. Also $\mathsf{E}Y=\mathsf{E}[\mathsf{E}[Y\mid X]]=2$.

Comment: I'm sorry for my ignorance, but how can this be used for finding E[XY] or the covariance?

Comment: $\operatorname{Cov}(X,Y)=\mathsf{E}[X^2+X]-\mathsf{E}X\mathsf{E}Y=3-2=\ldots$

Comment: Oh okay, I didn't know $E[x^2+X]$ could be rewritten as $E[X^2]+E[X]$, thank you!